# Condition assignment to boolean

Tags: c++, c

Emulating booleans in C can be done this way:

```
int success;
success = (errors == 0 && count > 0);
if(success)
   ...
```

With `stdbool.h` included following could be done:

```
bool success;
success = (errors == 0 && count > 0) ? true : false;
if(success)
   ...
```

From what I understand logical and comparison operators should return either 1 or 0.
Also, `stdbool.h` constants should be defined so that `true == 1` and `false == 0`.

Thus following should work:

```
bool success;
success = (errors == 0 && count > 0);
if(success)
   ...
```

And it does work on compilers that I have tested it with. But is it safe to assume it is portable code? (Assume that `stdbool.h` exists)

Is the situation different on C++ compilers as bool is internal type?

Comment: Actually, any non-zero value is considered true, while zero is false.

Comment: C since C99 has a Boolean type. It is named `_Bool` and the macro `bool` in stdbool.h is just a textual replacement for that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That's true, but any time when C *generates* a boolean value it's either 0 or 1. `const int a = (b > c);` will never make `a` equal 42.

Comment: @unwind And in C++, an expression like `b > c` has type `bool`, and is either `true` or `false` (not `1` or `0`).  Only if the `bool` is converted to another type does it become `1` or `0`.

Comment: The proper way to code C is to _pretend_ that expressions like (errors == 0) is essentially boolean. To treat the result of any of the `> < >= <= == != ! && ||` operators as bool in C is perfectly safe, perfectly portable and considered good programming style.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is safe to assume. In C99, upon conversion to the `_Bool` type, all non-zero values are converted to 1. This is described in section 6.3.1.2 in the C99 standard. The equality and relational operators (e.g. `==`, `>=`, etc) are guaranteed to result in either 1 or 0 as well. This is described in section 6.5.8 and 6.5.9.

For C++, the `bool` type is a real Boolean type where values are converted to `true` or `false` rather than 1 or 0, but it is still safe to assign the result of an `==` operation etc. to a `bool` and expect it to work, because the relational and comparison operators result in a `bool` anyway. When `true` is converted to an integer type it is converted to 1.

Comment: In C++ the situation is completely different anyway, since the comparison and logical operators return `bool` directly, so assigning it to `bool` is safe by nature and there aren't any integral conversions involved at all.

Comment: @ChristianRau: That's right, I had a sneaking suspicion that those operators resulted in `bool` but didn't want to say it without knowing it (I didn't have the C++ spec in front of me). I edited my answer.

Comment: Ok, I looked it up, section 5.9 (and following) state that the return value is `bool`.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `(errors == 0 && count > 0)` has type `bool`, and
can be used anywhere a `bool` is required, including assigning
it to a variable of type `bool`, or using it in a condition. 
(When converted to another integral type, `false` converts to 0,
and `true` to 1, but there's no question of that in your code.)

Note that in C, with `<stdbool.h>`, `bool` is supposed to behave
exactly as it does in C++ (although for various historical
reasons, the actual specification is different).  This means
that something like:

```
bool success = (errors == 0 && count > 0) ? true : false;
```

is *not* really something that you'ld want to write.  The
expression `errors == 0 && count > 0` has a type which is
compatible with `bool`, and can be used as an expression of type
`bool`.  (In C++, of course, the type isn't just compatible with
`bool`, it is `bool`.)

Comment: The difference is that in C++, (errors == 0) evaluates to a type bool with size 1 bytes, but in C it evaluates to the type int and has size 2 or 4 bytes. And because of integer promotion rules in C, it doesn't matter if both operands are 1 byte variables, the result would still be an int. As far as I know, C++ overrides the integer promotion of bool variables, as long as they are used in a boolean expression == && etc, rather than in an arithmetic one, where they would get promoted to int just like in C.

Comment: @Lundin It's true that `sizeof(errors == 0)` will be `sizeof(bool)` in C++ and `sizeof(int)` in C, but is there any realistic context where that can make a difference?  Also: integral promotion is irrelevant here; in both languages, the resulting type is the same, regardless of the types being compared (which is where integral promotion comes in).  And `bool` is not subject to integral promotion in C++; it is in C.  But you're misusing `bool` if you use it in a context where this would be detectable.

Comment: @Lundin And the sizes of `bool` and `int` are implementation defined; an implementation could even make `bool` larger than `int`.  (Of course, anything larger than `int` for `bool` would be very dubious in terms of QoI.)  And `int` isn't only 2 or 4.  I'm aware of an implementation where it was 6, for example.

Comment: As for realistic cases, integer promotions typically only cause problems when you intentionally or accidentally happen to mix signed integers with bitwise operators, or with hex literals. I suppose that if you mix bool with any of those, you might end up with some pitfalls. But then, you have probably written some obscure nonsense code in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the juicy part of the `stdbool.h` on my system:

```
#define bool    _Bool
#if __STDC_VERSION__ < 199901L && __GNUC__ < 3
typedef int     _Bool;
#endif

#define false   0
#define true    1
```

C99 has the type `_Bool` built in, and it converts all non-zero values to 1 (as has been said). However, a quick look at my `stdbool.h` shows that even in the absence of C99, it is safe to assume this stuff will work with the one caveat that a value not equal to zero *or* one assigned to a `_Bool` will *not* be converted to 1 (since `_Bool` is a simple `int` typedef rather than a built-in type with special properties) and therefore will not `== true`.

Comment: Bad system! It is wonderfully stupid to have a signed type as bool. On that system, `_Bool b = 1; ... if(~b > false)` and other such expressions would evaluate to 0, since the bitwise operator happened to set the sign bit. Lets hope this stdbool.h was from "Bob's Garage compiler" and not one of the major commercial ones.

Comment: Safest approach seems to be to avoid using comparison or bitwise operators with bool types at all. I cannot even think one situation where those would be useful anyway.

Comment: @Lundin No, actually, this version of `stdbool.h` came with my fairly new Macbook that's running the latest associated software. My Linux machine has a different version that seems to have come with gcc, and it doesn't support the pre-C99 case at all.

Comment: @Lundin Since the ~ causes type promotion to int for the _Bool type the expression would behave properly albeit not as expected. As ~b equals -2 then statement becomes if( -2 > 0 ) and should always evaluate to false.

Comment: @Kenneth The type was already int, so there will be no integer promotion. This can't be considered as anything else but a major compiler bug: they should have used unsigned int. Nobody will ever expect a boolean to hold a negative value. This typedef must have caused thousands of end application bugs over the years...

Comment: @Lundin: Not necessarily. The standard does not specify the representation of _Bool, nor its sign. It only states that _Bool 'is large enough to store the values 0 and 1' (6.2.5) and that objects are composed of 'one or more bytes' (6.2.6.1). My guess is that compilers use int to keep it compatible with the return value of relational and logical operators.